# Where is the configuration file of a lxc container?

Tags: networking, lxc, lxd

I installed [`lxd`](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd) to use linux containers. For some reason I keep using `lxc` commands to install and start my containers. Since `lxd` seems to be close to `lxc` maybe there is a reason for that (but it is not clear).

I wanted to bind two `lxc` containers to two different bridges, different from the default `lxcbr0` one. I created `br1` and `br2` and gave them IP addresses. They work fine and are pingable.

I am now trying to locate the place where I should change the configuration of my containers (`cont1` and `cont2`) in order to have their `eth0` (the interface name can be kept the same for each of those guests) bound to respectively `br1` and `br2`.

The [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-network) states that

> Then, specify the host's bridge in the container configuration file in
>   place of lxcbr0, for instance

**Where is this configuration file?**

At the top of this documentation page, there is information about con[figuration files](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-global-conf):

> The following configuration files are consulted by LXC. For privileged
>   use, they are found under /etc/lxc, while for unprivileged use they
>   are under ~/.config/lxc.
>
> lxc.conf may optionally specify alternate values for several lxc
>   settings, including the lxcpath, the default configuration, cgroups to
>   use, a cgroup creation pattern, and storage backend settings for lvm
>   and zfs.
>
> default.conf specifies configuration which every newly created
>   container should contain. This usually contains at least a network
>   section, and, for unprivileged users, an id mapping section
>
> lxc-usernet.conf specifies how unprivileged users may connect their
>   containers to the host-owned network.
>
> lxc.conf and default.conf are both under /etc/lxc and
>   $HOME/.config/lxc, while lxc-usernet.conf is only host-wide.
>
> By default, containers are located under /var/lib/lxc for the root
>   user, and $HOME/.local/share/lxc otherwise. The location can be
>   specified for all lxc commands using the "-P|--lxcpath" argument.

If I read it correctly, it does not indicate where the **container config file** is.

The configuration I would like to add for `cont1` is

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br1
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.10.11.0/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 10.10.11.11
```

and I tried to put it in the files `/etc/lxc/cont1/config` and `/var/lib/lxc/cont1/config` but none was taken into account: the container does not start, failing to bring up the networking. It works fine with the default config using `lxcbr0`.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but in case someone else is - like I was - searching for an answer to this "obvious" question:

The config file for a privileged container seems to be in `/var/lib/lxc/${containerName}/config`.

Answer (score 1):

Place configuration file for LXC container in any place and then specify this file when creating a container with -f option:

```
lxc-create {-n name} [-f config_file] {-t template} [-B backingstore] [-- template-options]
```

for example:

```
sudo lxc-create -t download -f /any/path/u1.container.conf -n u1 -- -d ubuntu -r xenial -a amd64
```